# Why would Activity.getPackageManager() return null

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, android-package-managers

I have method that resolves an Intent to a ComponentName:

```
private static ComponentName resolveViewExternalIntent(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = createIntent();
    return intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager());
}
```

Rarely, I get the following ACRA crash report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.Intent.resolveActivity(Intent.java:4518)
    at com.mypackage.myclass.resolveViewExternalIntent(SourceFile:271)
    at om.mypackage.myActivity.onResume(SourceFile:517)
```

That line in the Intent class gets the NPE because PackageManager is `null`.

I see this infrequently, but frequently enough that made me write this question.

Does anybody have any idea, under what circumstances can Context/Activity.getPackageManager() return null?  In my case, `context` is the Activity object itself, not the ApplicationContext.  The app is executing the Activity.onResume() lifecycle method when this happens.

Comment: Your context is not null for sure ?

Comment: If it were, would I get that stack trace?  So, no, context cannot be null.

Comment: Besides, I call this resolveViewExternalIntent(this) where 'this' is the Activity, so it's impossible it to be null.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the intent with an intent action or an explicit intent. You can try this:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ZZZ); // Replace ZZZ
```

and then call the package manager to check that those applications or features are available on your device.